# Angular 4 routing component in component

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I have a `DashboardComponent` that is being loaded if the router is at `/client` and the same for `/product`:

```
export const routes: Routes =
[
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'client', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: 'product', component: DashboardComponent }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class RoutesModule { }
```

And I then load the different components in like this (in `dashboard.component.ts`):

```
this.router.events.subscribe(path => {

    if (this.router.url == "/client") {
        this.isClient = true;
    }

    if (this.router.url != "/client") {
        this.isClient = false;
    }
    if (this.router.url == "/product") {
        this.isProduct = true;
    }

    if (this.router.url != "/product") {
        this.isProduct = false;
    }

});
```

Then in the `dashboard.component.html` I do:

```
<app-client *ngIf="isClient"></app-client>
<app-product *ngIf="isProduct"></app-product>
```

I feel like this is not the way to do it but I cannot find a good explanation on how to implement that if you go to e.g. `/dashboard/client` it loads the `ClientComponent` inside of the `DashboardComponent` and the same for `ProductComponent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with child router-outlets

```
// routing.module.ts
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'client',
                component: ClientComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'product',
                component: ProductComponent
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and add the child router outlet to your `DashboardComponent`

```
<div>
    dashboard component
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

So when the user goes to `/dashboard/client`, `DashboardComponent` is loaded in the top level router-outlet, and `ClientComponent` is loaded into the child router-outlet (inside of `DashboardComponent`). Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inatsc?file=app%2Frouting%2Frouting.module.ts) demoing this

Comment: @MeesKluivers as a side note, I would add another route definition under `DashboardComponent` `children: [{path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'client'}]` so when the user hits just `/dashboard` they are redirected to `/dashboard/client`. I've updated my stackblitz

Comment: Ah I see, what I did was add the path:‘’ and then load the ClientComponent. Thanks!